# Embedding Adobe Type Basics T1 Postscript fonts in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, pdftex

Recently I acquired the Adobe Type Basics T1 package and I am using Acrobat Distiller for the ps2pdf option (Winedt 8.0 + MikTeX 2.9). If I create a file using latex-dvi2ps-ps2pdf, the Times Roman/Courier fonts are embedded in the .pdf file. The problem is with Beamer, I have to use the PDFTexify option and it changes my fonts to Nimbus.

Is there any way to embed this kind of fonts with PDFTexify?

I have already seen the updmap.cfg file and the option *pdftexDownloadBase14* is set to true.

My other question is related to the GS viewer. When using dvi2ps, I don't get the Courier font with texttt. However, when I convert that .ps file to .pdf using Acrobat Distiller (prepress) I recover the "fancy" fonts. I am telling this because printing from the .ps file (with Windows GDI Printer) gives me better results than from the "Distilled" .pdf.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Change the LW35 option in updmap.cfg.

Comment: Thanks! the problem is when I try to edit the file. I go to the command prompt and write initexmf --edit-config-file updmap. After that I can see a notepad file with no text. I add #LW35
LW35 ADOBE and save. After running initexmf --mkmaps and updmap there is no change in the .cfg file. Is this the correct way to edit the updmap file?

Comment: Why should the configuration file (cfg) change if you run updmap? Check the created pdftex.map. If I add `LW35 ADOBE` to my .cfg then the map entry for e.g. `ptmb8r` changes from `ptmb8r NimbusRomNo9L-Medi ...` to `ptmb8r Times-Bold ....`

Comment: I understand, the problem is that MiKTeX can't find the .pfb files. The error says "!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file com____.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading". I installed the .pfm files on Windows with the right click option but did nothing with the .pfb. I guess I have to somehow "install" these T1 text fonts in MiKTeX. Am I right? Can you give me some tips? Thank you.

Comment: Put the `.pfb` in a folder "myfonts/fonts/type1/adobe", then add "myfonts" as a new root in miktex settings.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. Anyway, other problem has appeared. Now it says "!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file C:/Users/John/Documents/myfonts/fonts/type1/a
dobe/tib_____.pfb): 38084 bytes more than expected" What does pdfTeX expect?

Comment: Sound as if your font is defective.

Comment: It's strange, those are original fonts and I have done nothing with them... Let's see if there is a way to solve this. Thank you very much for your help.